# Rewrite rules with query-string for multiple URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I would like to redirect all URLs as follows

```
http://domain.com/?s=25 ...> http://domain.com/s=25.html
```

For each URL I can do the folowing:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)s\=25($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /s=25.html?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I want to rewrite everything following the "?"

For example:

```
 /?s=25        ...> /s=25.html
 /?cat=2       ...> /cat=2.html
 /?page_id=25 ...> /page_id=25.html
```

How can I do this for multiple files with a single rule?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there really an `=` in the name of your html file?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is

Comment: Although the output file name could be changed if needed to remove the =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you with one rule. Give this a try and let me know.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(page_id|cat|s)=(.+)(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1=%2.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Could I ask a further question?

Comment: What would be the best way to redirect /s=100 to /s=100.html